# drop rownames when subsetting dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data frame with rownames and colnames. For example:

```
            A       B       C   
    A       1       5       6   
    B       3       1       2   
    C       8       1       4
```

I want to subset only column A and C. my code is

```
    df[c("A","C"),c("A","C")]
```

It doesn't work. It gives NA for the subsetted matrix. It seems when I subsetted with rownames, the rownames disappear. How can I solve this? I tried adding drop=FALSE, it still doesn't work.

Comment: If it is a `data.frame`, it is working for me

Comment: It also works for me.

Comment: check your vectors.  I thought I was getting the same thing, but then realized I had written `df[c("A, C"), ...`.  I hadn't properly quoted "A" and "C".  Perhaps it's a simple typo.

Comment: You might also have a `tbl_df` from the `tibble` package or other tidyverse packages. They tend to avoid rownames.

Comment: I should check again, maybe in the middle of processing, the dataframe changes into matrix and I didn't realize it.